# Is it that wrong to use table instead of css' float?

Tags: css, css-float, css-tables

I've made websites before it was really used, and I've made the decision years ago to use CSS to design my webpages. It was a lot of trouble to leave the great tables and try "clearing both" instead.

The question is, after all those years I still have trouble sometimes. And everytime I run into a bad CSS situation I recall the easy way to make cols with "table".

And the more I'm thinking about it, and the less I understand why we dropped the use of table. They are great to design pages, and not every websites need to be 100% W3C conform or have hundreds of page that wouldn't support a change of design because of that.

So yeah, now I'm thinking about going back using tables. Should I do it? Do pro designers actually use tables where they shouldn't use them?

I also stumbled into a grotesque table in the google map API. If google ingeneers are taking that shortcut, why not me?

(sorry for my english I'm not fluent).

EDIT:

lot of response says it's my fault. I considered being pretty good in CSS, started with books of Eric Meyer and have been doing CSS since 2005. I know that the trick `width:100%;overflow:auto;` works in most case (and also that we didn't have this trick bad then), but I wonder if it would be a bad thing to use tables to quickly do the job on smalls website, like a blog.

Comment: There are tables all over google stuff.  Even their search page is nested tables.

Comment: Just read this comic: http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html

Comment: "*And everytime I run into a bad css situation I recall the easy way to make cols with "table"*"... you should instead recall that it's time to take a good CSS layouts tutorial... `:P`

Comment: Why not be crap if other people (Google) are being crap?  Surely you see the problem with that.

Comment: No CSS was crap and you should have admitted it. Now this is fixed with the new CSS grids and flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6 years later (we're now in 2017) and CSS now has [grids](http://cssgridgarden.com/) and [flexbox](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) which should be the easiest way to build a layout without using ugly hacks and without using tables.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues when I started dropping tables and using CSS. Sometimes CSS floats can be a pain, there are a few tricky edge-cases that come up when using them for page layout, but you'll learn how to deal with them and it really is worth it. Your code will be 10% of the size and much easier to work with.

Another consideration is CSS floats can be made to work nicely with mobile devices and small screens. Tables can cause real issues with this, especially if you want to add nice touchscreen improvements.

Lots of "pro" designers use tables when they shouldn't. All over the place. But "pro" is often not the same as "good". Tables should only be used for visible tables of data.

Answer (score 1):

Tables still have an important and semantically correct correct usage.  That is for the display of tabular data.  That is especially useful in envirnments that are DB-centric or that are process a lot of xml with ajax.  For general layout they are not appropriate because the cause slow page loading because the browser has to wait for all contents before it can start rendering. CSS should not be difficult. If you are having trouble you should look at how it is being used on sites where you like the design.

The big advantage of CSS is that you can develop a master stylesheet for a site, and then where individual pages need slight variations you can apply overrides or modifications to specific elements without having to change the master sheet.

Answer (score 1):

avoiding table layouts offers up a plethora of benefits but @ the end of the day, browsers are still entirely too forgiving (currently) and you can get away with it. if you are wary of going back to them, read up on display:table and css3. it's practically table based layouts, minus the table.

Answer (score 0):

One reason tables are avoided is that the content inside of them does not display until the HTML for the entire table has loaded.  With the CSS method, this is not true.

If you really have a lot of trouble with the CSS method, you must be doing it wrong.  Consider reading over other people's code to see how to do it better.